# Material Ui: Change mu icons props in array dinamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, icons

I need change props (color, size) for many icons in array (and I use mu v4):

```
const ICONS_ARRAY: React.ReactNode[] = [
<AlertCircleCheckOutline />,
<AppleSafari />,
<MotionPlay />,
<AppleKeyboardCommand />,
<FileDocumentMultipleOutline />,
<ClipboardArrowLeftOutline />,
<ViewDashboardOutline />,
<CalendarClockOutline />,
<RobotHappyOutline />,
<AccountWrenchOutline />,
<AccountGroupOutline />,
<AccountCogOutline />,
<RunFast />,
<SpeedometerSlow />]
```

I try this (i - index icon in array):

```
           <MenuItem>
                <Box>
                    <SvgIcon fontSize={'small'}>ICONS_ARRAY[i]</SvgIcon>
                </Box>
            </MenuItem>,
```

But icon not render.
If I change ICONS_ARRAY[i] on element - it works, like this:

```
           <MenuItem>
                <Box>
                    <SvgIcon fontSize={'small'}><RunFast /></SvgIcon>
                </Box>
            </MenuItem>
```

Also I try React.cloneElement, but it work same.

So you have any idea what the problem could be and what is the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to say something small, but just to dismiss.
Have you tried adding brackets "{}"? 
something like this...

```
        <MenuItem>
            <Box>
                <SvgIcon fontSize={'small'}>{ICONS_ARRAY[i]}</SvgIcon>
            </Box>
        </MenuItem>
```

Or try this

```
    {ICONS_ARRAY.map((icon) => (
      <MenuItem>
        <SvgIcon fontSize={"small"}>{icon}</SvgIcon>
      </MenuItem>
    ))}
```

Comment: oh God, you are right! Apparently I need a rest *facepalm*. Thank you!